# Improperly called Javascript function (parameter issue)

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to echo some HTML using PHP in a div.  Everything was working until I tried to pass a parameter to the onclick=\"loadpuzzle()\" function.  It ran fine when I tried onclick=\"loadpuzzle(4)\" and the function took the parameter and executed normally, but what I need is to pass the value from $row['puzzlename'] as the parameter, which I assume is a string (and so I enclosed it in quotation marks).

```
echo "<td><input id=\"".$row['puzzlename']."\" type=\"radio\" name=\"puzzle-set\"     class=\"puzzle_selector\"  onclick=\"loadpuzzle(\"".$row['puzzlename']."\")\"/>  
        <label for=\"".$row['puzzlename']."\" class=\"puzz_label\">".$row['puzzlename']."</label></td>";
```

I am getting a weird error in Safari when I try to run this.  "Unexpected token:  '}' ".

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  Why won't it take this parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you could post the codes around this piece of code too

Comment: Can you provide an example of the generated markup that's being `echo`ed?

Comment: Sorry?  the codes around what piece of code?  I'd be happy to, I'm just not sure what you mean :)

Comment: What do you mean a markup?  I'm sorry!  Haha I'm new to PHP/Javascript.

Comment: it says `Unexpected token: }`. clearly this isn't the only code in your php right? maybe you could post more as it is incomplete and cant be diagnosed further.

Comment: Oh, okay!  I will post the entire contents of the div.  But the unexpected token : } isn't the problem.  It's just the debugger wigging out and trying to come up with an excuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try escaping all of your double quotes like your doing or perhaps switch to single quotes for readability.

```
echo '<td><input id="' . $row['puzzlename'] . '" type="radio" name="puzzle-set" class="puzzle_selector" onclick="loadpuzzle(\'' . $row['puzzlename'] . '\')"/>
      <label for="' . $row['puzzlename'] . '" class="puzz_label">' . $row['puzzlename'] . '</label></td>';
```

Comment: Oh... I thought double quotes were required in some of those places.  Thank you!  I'll have to go read up on the difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<td><input id=\"".$row['puzzlename']."\" type=\"radio\" name=\"puzzle-set\"         class=\"puzzle_selector\"  onclick=\"loadpuzzle(\"".$row['puzzlename']."\")\"/>  
<label for=\"".$row['puzzlename']."\" class=\"puzz_label\">".$row['puzzlename']."</label></td>";
```

Since you are using onclick=\"loadpuzzle(\"".$row['puzzlename']."\") it will render into onclick="loadpuzzle("puzzlename")".
Instead of sending parameters using double quotes use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry, the last person beat you to it, but I appreciate your answer nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first double quote for the function parameter is actually closing the opening double quote for the onclick definition. Use a single quote instead like this:

```
echo "<td><input id=\"".$row['puzzlename']."\" type=\"radio\" name=\"puzzle-set\" class=\"puzzle_selector\"  onclick=\"loadpuzzle('".$row['puzzlename']."')\" /><label for=\"".$row['puzzlename']."\" class=\"puzz_label\">".$row['puzzlename']."</label></td>";
```

I would also think about rewriting this entire output to use WAY less escaping. It becomes increasingly unreadable and *ahem* error prone.

Comment: You're the best!  This worked :)  darn, I thought the \ tokens would take care of that... I guess not.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, I will definitely consider writing this output to be more readable and less error prone.  I think ANY programmer would.  I just don't have the know-how and right now I'm at the stage where if it works, it works.  Thank you for the suggestion though.